# Facebook open graph meta tag: fb-admins

Tags: meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I'm going over Facebook's Open Graph API. All of it seems simple and is explained well except for the `fb:admins` meta tag. What is this for?

For example:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
```

Facebook says this: A comma-separated list of either Facebook user IDs or a Facebook Platform application ID that administers this page. It is valid to include both fb:admins and fb:app_id on your page. I'm just not sure what this is.

I guess it is the combination of the ids that is tripping me up.

Comment: Looks like it is an either or on the ids

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you any of the social plugins, fb will look at the fb:admins tag to determine access to admin features directly from your site. For example, if you use the comment box, and you have `<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>` with your fbid, while logged in, it'll give you access to moderate the comment box. At least, thats my understanding

Comment: Indeed. And you can add more than one administrator's Facebook UID into the meta tag by adding them comma-separated.

Comment: Actually you would add a seperate fb:admins tag for each user, not comment them as that returns invalid.

Comment: I know this is old but just pointing out that the above comment that commas is wrong, is false in case you find this through a search like I did. You are supposed to only use one fb:admins meta tag with comma separated user_ids. Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: Another update for those who see it. Today the fb dev site says `Note: Additional fb:admins should be declared in a new tag.`